# cant view validation errors while using getOrderHash

Tags: 0x

i am trying to hash my order like this

```
import { orderHashUtils } from '@0x/order-utils';
orderHashUtils.getOrderHash(order,1,"0x080bf510FCbF18b91105470639e9561022937712")
```

but i am getting validation errors . but i cant view those errors cause they look like this

```
Error: Expected order to conform to schema /orderSchema
Validation errors: [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]
```

i have tried catching the error as "e" but how do i log the validation errors in readable forms

what is the correct  orderSchema to use as all versions have different schema ? does the 3rd argument in getOrderHash specify the exchange address thus decide what scheme is correct ?

Comment: figured the schema from here - > https://runkit-packages.com/14.x.x/1630603101060/@0x/order-utils/node_modules/@0x/json-schemas/lib/schemas/order_schema.json 

still confused why i need to send takerFeeAssetData in fields when i am using v2.1 exchange . does the function automatically remove the extra fields ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to create Exchange v2.1 orders. The current `@0x/order-utils` package is for exchange v3. I believe the last version that supported v2.1 of the Exchange was `@0x/order-utils@8.4.0`.